# What is widening factor "k" in a CNN?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm studying the CNN
[image]

The description for the variables is given as

```
Residual units are shown in brackets. where k is the widening
factor, N denotes the number of blocks in group (We use k = 2,
N = 2
```

I would like to know what `k` actually means and also, how would you implement it in a keras Conv2D layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "residual unit" is an aggregate of operations (all those in the bracket, plus some a merging operation at the end of the unit), not a single convolution.

`k` is just a multiplier hyperparameter that scales up each operation's depth `k` times (e.g., with `k=2`, the `1x1 64*k` conv in the `Conv2` block will have depth 128).
Implementing this is straightforward, just directly use as number of filters in your `Conv2D` the expression. for example, the convolution op I mention above would be implemented as:

```
# in __init__ or where you build your network
_conv2_with_64xk_filters = keras.layers.Conv2D(64*k, (1,1))
```

**Note:** Since `k` is a hyperparameter, it has to be known at network build time, which is why I assume you have it available in your build function.